# Returning objects using JSONRESPONSE

Tags: django

I'm trying to return an object using Jsonresponse, Sorry im newb
This is my script:

```
setInterval(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/check_notification/',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {}
        });
    }, 2000);
```

in my django views.py:

```
def check_notification(request):
    user = request.user
    profile = Person.objects.get(profile=user)
    notification = NotificationRecipient.objects.filter(profile=profile)
    return JsonResponse(model_to_dict(notification))
```

Comment: And what happens?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a model Serializers for models you want to pass as response. for more information read django rest framework [tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) about serializers an learn how to make json response. Or if you have a simple dictionary you can make json response with this code snippet at the end of your `check_notification` function. `return HttpResponse(json.dumps(your dictionary))`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use Django Rest Framework for returning Responses in JSON format as the Serialization of models can be don easily. You can start from [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/). There you will find something known as a ModelSerializer. Basically you create a serializer.py in your app folder with the following content:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Person, NotificationRecipient


class PersonSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = '__all__'



class NotificationRecipientSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = NotificationRecipient
            fields = '__all__'
```

The above code will serialize your models which means will be converted to json format.
Than in a file named as views_api.py, you can create a class that will be called using by the URL and will have your queryset defined. In your case the class will be defined as:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Person, NotificationRecipient
from .serializers import NotificationRecipientSerializers

class NotificationAPIView(APIView): 

    def get(self,request):
            user = request.user
            profile = Person.objects.get(profile=user)
            notification = NotificationRecipient.objects.filter(profile=profile)
            return Response(notification)
```

This will return the response in JSON format. In your urls.py file call the NotificationAPIView as follows:

from django.urls import path
   from .import views_api

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('check/notification/', views_api.NotificationAPIView.as_view(), name='notification'),

   ]
```

Hope you get a basic understanding of what is going on there. For better understanding go through Django Rest Framework docs.

Comment: How can i access it in my template? can I use ajax?